# EF Code First Optional Navigation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following POCO objects:

```
public class Chat
{
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public virtual Audio ChatAudio { get; set; }
    public virtual Video ChatVideo { get; set; }
}

public class Audio
{
    public int AudioID { get; set; }
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public DateTime Recorded { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public int VideoID { get; set; }
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public DateTime Recorded { get; set; }
}
```

DBA has the following tables setup

```
-Chat-
ChatID

-Audio-
AudioID
ChatID <-- FK, Unique Index
Recorded

-Video-
VideoID
ChatID <-- FK, Unique Index
Recorded
```

So this is a 1-to-optional relationship. He doesn't want to create a nullable column for Audio or Video on the Chat table. How can I force this to work in EF Code First? The only way I've gotten this to work is to make those navigational properties collections and defined HasMany(). I do not want that. I want to be able to do:

```
if(Chat.Audio == null || Chat.Video==null)
{
// Do stuff
}
```

I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: True 1 to 1 relationships are rare in my experience. (It usually implies there is a hierarchy). You have a chat with optional recorded audio and video. Is there data about Audio and Video that we're missing? I'm not seeing the purpose of the schema.

Comment: i just ommited irrelevant properties on chat to keep it brief.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot map this model to your database schema with Entity Framework (no matter which version up to current version 4.2).

The main reason is that EF doesn't support unique key constraints, which means: mapping a reference navigation property to a column in the database which has a unique key constraint. EF will consider such a FK column in the database always as not unique and doesn't see the unique key constraint. So, the ends of the two associations in `Chat` must be collections. Or you could not expose them in your model, but internally EF will consider them always as "many"-ends.

The only true one-to-one relationship which EF supports are shared primary key relationships. It would mean that you don't have a `ChatId` column in the `Audio` and `Video` table but instead the primary key columns `AudioId` and `VideoId` are foreign key columns to the `Chat` table at the same time. Obviously the primary key columns cannot be all autogenerated identities in the database to make this kind of mapping possible.

A great description for both one-to-one mapping strategies and a comparison of their benefits and limitations can be found here:

- [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)
- [One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

Comment: thx for the links. i had read them before but perhaps i missed something. Question, could perhaps some sort of configuration that defines an inheritance work here with the same table structure?

Comment: @ludwigs3rd: No. Because for this table structure you would have to setup TPT mapping and to build the relation between base class table and tables for derived classes EF uses internally again shared primary key associations. Moreover the primary key columns for all involved tables must have the same name, so you could not use `ChatId` in base table and `AudioId` in the Audio derived table. The PK column must also have the name `ChatId`.

Answer (score 0):

You could "cheat" and configure the the relationship as one to many, enforcing the one to one in the object model (also, in the datacontext initializer you can manually add the unique constraint to the database).

It would basically look something like this

```
public class Chat 
{ 
    public int ChatID { get; set; } 
    protected virtual ICollection<Audio> HiddenAudioCollection{get;set;}
    public Audio ChatAudio 
    { 
      get{return HiddenAudioCollection.FirstOrDefault();} 
      set
      {
        if(HiddenAudioCollection==null)
          HiddenAudioCollection=new List<Audio>();
        if(HiddenAudioCollection.Any())
        {
          //decide if you throw an exception or delete the existing Audio
        }

        HiddenAudioCollection.Add(value);
      } 
    } 
    //Do the same with ChatVideo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand this correctly:

Chat has zero or one Audio, and zero or one Video.

Audio, if it exists, belongs to exactly 1 Chat.
Video, if it exists, belongs to exactly 1 Chat.

Is this correct? If so, would your DBA mind a schema like this?

```
-Chat-
ChatID

-Audio-
ChatID <-- FK, Primary Key
Recorded

-Video-
ChatID <-- FK, Primary Key
Recorded
```

If so, I think you can do this:

```
public class Chat
{
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public virtual Audio ChatAudio { get; set; }
    public virtual Video ChatVideo { get; set; }
}

public class Audio
{
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public virtual Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public DateTime Recorded { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public virtual Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public DateTime Recorded { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Audio>().HasKey(a => a.ChatID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Video>().HasKey(a => a.ChatID);
    var chat = modelBuilder.Entity<Chat>();
    chat
        .HasOptional(c => c.ChatAudio)
        .WithRequired(a => a.Chat);

    chat
        .HasOptional(c => c.ChatVideo)
        .WithRequired(a => a.Chat);
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since the Video and Audio "belong" to the chat is to use a complex structure. Don't give the Video and Audio their own Id, they will be mapped to the chat table. I know that some DBA's hate this idea because it's optional data. But technically it's no different than storing an Address in a Customer table directly. It all depends on how normalized you want your database to be.